# catching exception raised in different project method

Tags: python, exception

I have a project X from which I am calling a function from the module m, in the module m I have defined a custom exeception called `XException(Exception)`

if an error happens in X.m.func I raise `XException` !

so the question is, as I am calling the func from X.m should I handle the raised exception in my this project Y, since in this project Y I am just calling the function like this `X.m.func()` in `Y.module.function` ?

Since when exception is raised execption of `Y.module.function` stops which is ok and which is what I want but not sure if I should handle the exception in Y project and log the message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want the exception to be thrown back to the user, then you should handle the exception in *Y* .

I believe its better to give a meaningful message back to the user after handling an exception rather than throwing the exception back to the user.

Unless what you are building is actually a framework, in which case your *users* would be other developers and then exceptions is the way to go.

Comment: thanks makes sense, I will document to avoid confusion in future.